# How can I use command line arguments with knitr source file?

Tags: r, knitr

I have an R script that accepts command line arguments that I want to convert to an Rtex or Rnw file to be knitted with a command like:

```
knit('myScript.Rtex "-args arg1=a arg2=b"')
```

but I cannot figure out how to get my command line arguments into myScript.Rtex [for evaluation therein by `args <- commandArgs()`]. I am trying to avoid writing temporary files that could contain the same information and be read by myScript.Rtex, because that seems unnecessarily untidy. Please can somebody provide a suggestion/solution?

So, long story short, how best to get information into a chunk in a .Rnw file that is equivalent (or at least similar) to processing command line arguments in a .R file?

### Edit: Incorporating code from comments below

I want to use them in the computation. For example, I had an R script run like

```
R CMD BATCH --slave --no-save --no-restore "--args input=blah" myScript.R
```

Now I'd like to pass the same argument to `myScript.Rnw`, which is a version of `myScript.R`, but interspersed LaTeX and R code chunks. So the broader issue is simply that for knitr report processing to be useful for me I need a way to change the data that the report is run on. I have a workaround - but I'd sure like to know if I can pass command line arguments to a chunk in my .Rnw file. Right now I cannot do that.

This is my workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ];
  then ` echo "Usage: $0 refdir cmpdir" exit 1`
fi
export CSPP_VIIRS_EDR_REFERENCE_DIR=$1
export CSPP_VIIRS_EDR_COMPARISON_DIR=$2
script=$(dirname $0)'/viirs_edr_UseR_compare.Rnw'
R --slave --no-save --no-restore -e "require(knitr); knit('$script')" &> viirs_edr_UseR_compare.log
pdflatex viirs_edr_UseR_compare.tex
exit 0
```

I use `Sys.getenv()` in *viirs_edr_UseR_compare.Rnw* to extract parameters I want to pass, e.g., **CSPP_VIIRS_EDR_REFERENCE_DIR**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to provide a solution called from bash with arguments passed through from the bash command line. So I think I will use the environment of that bash instance and pick up what I need with Sys.getenv(). It is a bit ugly, but I need to push on.

Comment: @jimdavies it is not clear what you want to do. looking at `knit` commandn it expected something like , ..`knit(input, output,...)`

Comment: this is the shell script I ship with `knitr`: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/bin/knit but it is not clear to me what you want to do with the `--args` -- do you want to pass them to `knit()`, or use them in your computation?

Comment: Use them in the computation. So, for example, if I had an R script that I used to run from the command line as

Comment: Use them in the computation. For example, I had an R script run like ...
`R CMD BATCH --slave --no-save --no-restore "--args input=blah" myScript.R`
... now I'd like to pass the same argument to myScript.Rnw which is a version of myScript.R, but interspersed LaTeX and R code chunks. So the broader issue is simply that for knitr report processing to be useful for me I need a way to change the data that the report is run on. I have a workaround - but I'd sure like to know if I can pass command line arguments to a chunk in my .Rnw file.  Right now I cannot do that.  Cheers, jim.

Comment: This is my workaround ...
`#!/bin/bash`
`if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then`
`  echo "Usage: $0 refdir cmpdir"`
`  exit 1`
`fi`
`export CSPP_VIIRS_EDR_REFERENCE_DIR=$1`
`export CSPP_VIIRS_EDR_COMPARISON_DIR=$2`
`script=$(dirname $0)'/viirs_edr_UseR_compare.Rnw'`
`R --slave --no-save --no-restore -e "require(knitr);`
`knit('$script')" &> viirs_edr_UseR_compare.log`
`pdflatex viirs_edr_UseR_compare.tex`
`exit 0`

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to put newlines in code fragments
is it `code\n`
Let's see - nope.  OK, so I then pick up the environment variables with `Sys.getenv()` - kinda ugly

Comment: @jimdavies if you want to clarify anything, please just edit your original post; the comments here are pretty restrictive in terms of writing and reading code

Answer (score 4):

You could write a R script instead of a bash one:

### my_script_launcher.R

```
library(knitr)
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
if (length(args) < 2) stop("Bad args, usage refdir cmpdir")

refdir <- args[1]
cmpdir <- args[2]

knit2pdf('my_script.Rnw')
```

### my_script.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
refdir=\Sexpr{refdir}
cmpdir=\Sexpr{cmpdir}
\end{document}
```

Then you launch it like this:

```
Rscript my_script_launcher.R foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up using the following commands (using `make`):

```
# set parameters
P1=some parameter
P2=some other parameter

# top target
all : report.html

# convert Markdown to HTML
%.html : %.md
    Rscript -e 'require(markdown);markdownToHTML("$<","$@")'

# knit Rmd passing parameters
%.md : %.Rmd
    Rscript -e 'param1<-$(P1);param2<-$(P2);require(knitr);knit("$<")'
```

In `report.Rmd` I can use `str(c(param1,param2))` in a code chunk and running `make` will produce an HTML file containing `chr [1:2] "some parameter" "some other parameter"`.

If you are not using `make`, just specify how you want to `knit` and where you are getting the parameters from and I can help you to adjust my solution to your needs.